# How to divide image into smaller pieces by line (plot) in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, split, binary, line

I want to ask a question about splitting a binary image. I tried to use the following code:

```
%# FAPatch is the binary image    
figure,imshow(FAPatch)  
hold on

%# PositionTab is a table that include the 3 outest point.
for i=1 :3  
    eval(['p' num2str(i) '= PositionTab(' num2str(i) ',:);']);  
end

%#C is the centroid [130,59]. And this is the code I use to draw the lines from centroid to the point  
plot([C(1),p1(2)],[C(2),p1(1)],[C(1),p2(2)],[C(2),p2(1)],[C(1),p3(2)],[C(2),p3(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
```

This is the table:

[image: PositionTab]

I get a binary image with lines:

[image: binary image with line]

How do I split this image into three small pieces? This is not a straight line and can be random, I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean...

Go to each of three points where the red lines meet the edges of the image. Use the points immediately above and below that if on a vertical edge, or the points immediately left and right of that if on a horizontal edge, as seed for a red flood fill, now make all red points transparent.

[image]